# Using NLP for extracting domain-specific data from unstructured text

Tags: java, nlp, data-mining, pos-tagger, information-extraction

I'm looking for a way to automatically extract domain-specific knowledge from unstructured text in Java. We would have a manually annotated training set at our disposal that contains the following:

Text: The apartment contains 2 bedrooms and one bathroom.
Structured
- Type: apartment
- Bedrooms: 2
- Bathrooms: 1

Any idea what's the best way forward to train a model that would be able to perform this job? Possibly a POS-tagger that we extend with custom tags?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the question is off topic. It is in fact very relevant and important. Can you add more examples to your question?

Comment: Since there are only a handful of good nlp libraries, these questions don't usually induce spam. I rephrased it. On the topic, I would recommend creating a rule based system, using GATE's jape or UIMA's TextMarker. You write regex-like rules like "match a number or lookup for numeric word, followed by a (plural) noun & lookup for room name" => "create NumRooms annotation". For a very restricted domain it should be easy to create term dictionaries and rules should be simple as well.